# Why eigenvector & eigenvalue in LDA become zero?

Tags: c++, opencv, probability, eigenvalue, linear-discriminant

I'd like to implement fast PLDA (Probabilistic Linear Discriminant Analysis) in OpenCV. in this, [LINK](https://sites.google.com/site/fastplda/) fast PLDA have been implemented in `Matlab` and `Python`. One of the parts of PLDA is LDA. I've written following code for implementing LDA in OpenCV:

```
int LDA_dim = 120;

// Load data

FileStorage fs("newStorageFile.yml", FileStorage::READ);

// Read data

Mat train_data, train_labels;

fs["train_data"] >> train_data;
fs["train_labels"] >> train_labels;

// LDA

if (LDA_dim > 0)
{
    LDA lda(LDA_dim);
    lda.compute(train_data, train_labels);          // compute eigenvectors

    Mat eigenvectors = lda.eigenvectors();
}
```

I've converted database that was introduced in above link from `.mat` to `.yml`. The result is `newStorageFile.yml` that I've uploaded [here](http://cdn.persiangig.com/download/hrHrCRpdCW/newStorageFile.yml/dl). `train_data` have 650 rows and 600 cols and train_labels have 650 rows and 1 cols. I don't know why eigenvectors and eigenvalue become zero!!? PLZ help me to fix this code.

It's better to bring the code that convert data from `.mat` to `.yml` :

```
function matlab2opencv( variable, fileName, flag)

[rows cols] = size(variable);

% Beware of Matlab's linear indexing
variable = variable';

% Write mode as default
if ( ~exist('flag','var') )
    flag = 'w'; 
end

if ( ~exist(fileName,'file') || flag == 'w' )
    % New file or write mode specified 
    file = fopen( fileName, 'w');
    fprintf( file, '%%YAML:1.0\n');
else
    % Append mode
    file = fopen( fileName, 'a');
end

% Write variable header
fprintf( file, '    %s: !!opencv-matrix\n', inputname(1));
fprintf( file, '        rows: %d\n', rows);
fprintf( file, '        cols: %d\n', cols);
fprintf( file, '        dt: f\n');
fprintf( file, '        data: [ ');

% Write variable data
for i=1:rows*cols
    fprintf( file, '%.6f', variable(i));
    if (i == rows*cols), break, end
    fprintf( file, ', ');
    if mod(i+1,4) == 0
        fprintf( file, '\n            ');
    end
end

fprintf( file, ']\n');

fclose(file);
```

Edit 1 ) I've tried LDA with some sample that myself generate:

```
Mat train_data = (Mat_<double>(3, 3) << 25, 45, 44, 403, 607, 494, 2900, 5900, 2200);
    Mat train_labels = (Mat_<int>(3, 1) << 1, 2, 3 );

    LDA lda(LDA_dim);

    lda.compute(train_data, train_labels);          // compute eigenvectors
    Mat_<double> eigenvectors = lda.eigenvectors();
    Mat_<double> eigenvalues = lda.eigenvalues();
    cout << eigenvectors << endl << eigenvalues;
```

but I've to got same result: eigenvalue and eigenvector become zero:
[image: eigenvector and eigenvalue]

Comment: @bytefish Since you've developed LDA in OpenCV, I think you can help me...

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem? I'm facing the same issue here, I save the lda.yml,  but when I open the file all vectors are 0.0

Comment: @Amir, No, I've changed my algorithm!!

Comment: First, mathematically eigenvector can't be zero (eigenvalues can be). Second, eigenvector and eigenvalues are defined for a square matrix. For non-square matrix are defined singular values. You are displaying three vectors (0,0), (1,0) and (0,1); and two eigenvalues 0 and 0.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the floating point imprecision that the eigen values get close to zero.